# Vectorizing and improving speed of R function

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

I've tried many things and I've been having quite a bit of trouble vectorizing this code.
I have managed to figure out a way of doing this with lapply but it's slightly slower than the code below. Note that data is sorted by `err` where `err` is increasing with the rows.

```
mySlowFunction <- function(data, vectorizedFunc){
  #data is a data.frame
  #vectorizedFunc is a function
  n <- d <- array(0, dim = c(nrow(data),1))
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
      err.i <- data$err[i]
      wt <- vectorizedFunc(data$X[i:nrow(data)] + err.i)
      n[i] <- sum(data$Y[i:nrow(data)] / wt)
      d[i] <- sum(1 / wt)
  }
  data$N.wt <- n
  data$D.wt <- d
  data
}

data <- data.frame(X = rnorm(10000), Y = rnorm(10000), err = rnorm(10000))
data <- data[order(data$err),]
system.time(mySlowFunction(data, exp))
```

My slightly slower lapply version:

```
myEvenSlowerFunction <- function(data, vectorizedFunc){
  #data is a data.frame
  res <- unlist(lapply(data$err, function(x) {
    idx <- which(data$err >= x)
    wt <- vectorizedFunc(data$X[idx] + x)
    c(sum(data$Y[idx] / wt), sum(1 / wt))
  }))
  idx <- seq(1,length(res) - 1,by=2)
  data$N.wt <- res[idx]
  data$D.wt <- res[idx + 1]
  data
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide some example data and code for `vectorizedFunc`? In particular, is it supposed to return a scalar or vector?

Comment: it returns a vector. Note that `data$X[i:nrow(data)]` is a vector. `vectorizedFunc` is any arbitrary function really. I edited the post so you can run the function on some 'data'

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

wait. isn't R is just using single thread ?
As far as I know, vectorization is for parallel computing....
If you are willing to use 'unrolling', this will greatly decrease the computation time.

```
myFunction <- function(data, vectorizedFunc){
  #data is a data.frame
  #vectorizedFunc is a function
  len=nrow(data)        ## if you are going to compute something over and over,  
                        ## justsave          them
  n = d = numeric(len)
  for (i in 1:len){
    err.i <- data$err[i]
    temp=data$X[i:len]   ## changed
    wt <- vectorizedFunc( temp+ err.i)
    n[i] <- sum(temp / wt)
    d[i] <- sum(1 / wt)
  }
  data$N.wt <- n
  data$D.wt <- d
  data
}

system.time(myFunction(data, exp))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   5.01    0.00    5.04 

#while your function gives

#   user  system elapsed 
#   6.15    0.02    6.20
```

Comment: thanks. that's just bad practice on my part. do you have any ideas on how to vectorize the function?

Comment: I have tried to think of ways to incorporate `cumsum` and/or `expand.grid` but I haven't thought hard enough. (memory is not a limitation for me)

Comment: Thank you for helping out! I'll know not to go down that route

Comment: No, vectorization is a standard tool for speeding up (and simplifying) code in a single 'thread.'

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is probably about as good as it gets. You're already vectorising the inner function call, and there don't seem to be any major gains to be had from further tweaking. Quite the opposite, in fact.

Here's a fully vectorised "solution", using `outer` to generate the `wt` variable. This is SLOWER than your code, mostly because 1) it requires creating an NxN matrix in memory, where N = `nrow(data)`; and 2) half of those matrix elements aren't necessary. Putting it out there to see if someone else can improve on it.

```
vecf <- function(data, vectorizedFunc)
{
    wt <- outer(data$e, data$X, "+")
    wt[lower.tri(wt)] <- NA
    wt <- vectorizedFunc(wt)
    data$N.wt <- rowSums(rep(data$Y, each=nrow(data))/wt, na.rm=TRUE)
    data$D.wt <- rowSums(1/wt, na.rm=TRUE)
    data
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is an interesting approach and hopefully it can be improved upon. It seems to be around 4 times slower

Comment: This is exactly what I've got when I did vectorize!

Comment: Yep. There's really nothing wrong with for loops. They used to be bad about 20 years ago, in the S-Plus days, but they've been tightened up a lot since then.